# How do I access HttpContext in Blazor WebAssembly as we can do in controller of API?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I would like to access HttpContext object to read data like headers, items and cookies.
I have to read data from httpcontext and use the same data to pass to API ahead.
I am kind of doing the way it is described in the igit ssue -https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22820
If its not possible, is there any other way to achieve what I want.

Note : User will be getting redirected to my website(Blazor webassembly) from another website(I don't have any control of this) this redirection will attach some data with the request(header,cookies etc). Now in my website I have to access that data present in request and pass it off to API as request headers.

Comment: From your link: "A Blazor WebAssembly application runs inside the user's browser sandbox, not in an ASP.NET Core server process. This would explain why it's unavailable." That seems like a conclusive answer, no?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what calls your page to show up is the routing service, that is in the server side, not in the client side.
I believe that there is not a client side way of capturing the requisition information directly.

If I’m not wrong, you’ll need  to work with the pipeline or implement an View controller (like asp.net MVC) that Will give you access to the request.